# Send Post request with Headers in Nestjs

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, request, nestjs

I am trying to use Nestjs to send a Post request to a 3rd party API which requires authorization (client-key and secret). Would anyone know how to attach headers in a request. I want to use axio's HttpService.

Answer (score 5):

give the `HttpService` post request a custom headers object

```js
this.httpService.post('http://www.stackoverflow.com', { my: 'data' }, { headers: { 'x-custom-header': "this a header" }})
```

would result in a `POST` request with `{ my: 'data' }` as payload and a custom header `x-custom-header: this is header`

underlying the nest `HttpService` there is an `axios` instance so you will find more information in the [axios doc](https://axios-http.com/docs/req_config)